# Table rendering problem in IE9

Tags: html

I'm not certain the problem is with IE9 and not other browsers, but I think that's a safe starting assumption.

When viewing [this web site](http://j-dezigns.co.za/web/metprep/) in IE9, I get a black horizontal line between the rows of the main layout table.  This is not visible in Firefox 4 and Chrome.

The body background is black, so I'm assuming there is a small gap between each of the rows.  The table declaration includes the following attributes, and there are no CSS rules in effect.

```
border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

What is most likely to be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have too much text in the cell with rowspan. It simply forces the table to be higher so that the images aren't high enough to cover their cells.

If you want to fill the cell with text to get the last paragraph exactly at the bottom (or just to use all of the available space in the cell), then you have to set the exact size of every element in the cell to override the different margins, paddings and line heights that different browsers have.

Another alternative to put a paragraph at the bottom is to use absolute positioning. Then the layout is not as sensetive to variations between browsers.

And, as John pointed out, you should of course have a doctype on the page so that it renders in Standards Compliance Mode instead of Quirks Mode, that will also help to reduce the difference between browsers.

Comment: Wow, your first paragraph too me at least a minute to grok :-)  Good thing I quoted a whole 2 hours for the fix.

Comment: I've now removed the two images in the rowspan cell entirely, and trimmed the bullet list to three items, with no change.

Comment: @ProfK: I just had to remove one of the empty paragraphs at the end of the cell to keep the cell from getting too large.

Comment: I've just removed all content from that cell with no difference.

Comment: @ProfK: I see, you have another problem that occurs in IE8 but not IE9. The images in the cells are inline elements, so they have a distance between the image bottom and the text line bottom, which makes them take up more space than their height. Apply the style `display:block` to the images. When you have an image inside a link tag, you have to apply the style to the link also.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

on the first line of html document, or just :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

it may help

Comment: That's certainly good advice, but it doesn't solve this specific problem.